# Google Cloud SQL Table Displaying Issues

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm having a problem where several of the tables I've created in Google Cloud SQL won't display correctly when I select them unless they have under 7 or so columns. Some table that I imported as CSVs show blanks for many entries that are not null when I use SELECT * FROM [table], but all entries display appropriately when I use SELECT [column] FROM [table], and I can do conditional queries with these entries, so I know that SQL knows what the entries should be. The tables with more columns that I built directly into SQL also add in a lot of weird spacing and place the vertical lines weirdly in the display.

I cut out the top portion of the first two rows of a table to show the sort of display issues I'm having with those tables. Entries near the bottom became single-spaced and everything like they should be. https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4OlR.png

Is there anything I can change about my code or Cloud SQL settings to make the tables reliably display appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the row is too wide for your terminal. Try making your terminal window wider and runnign the query again.

You can also end your query with `\G` instead of `;` to [display results in a vertical format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tips.html#vertical-query-results).

Comment: Thank you! This fixes some of the tables.

Comment: Do you have any further suggestions for the imported tables where it simply shows no data in some fields, but allows it to be queried accurately? Ending lines with \G will retrieve their data, but expanding the window well beyond the table width still doesn't display them.

Comment: The screenshot you shared does not show any empty entries - the blank space is belongs to the second line of each record after it has wrapped around. If you are seeing something else, please share another screenshot.